# Java : how to send x emails per minute

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I need to send a customized email to 400 clients.
I am doing this :

```
for (Client c : clients){
  setUpEmail(c);
  sendMail(c);
}
```

My problem is that my email provider authorizes me to send only 10 emails per minute. How could I do that in the loop?
Thanks.

Comment: add a counter. for each multiplication of ten, add a timer that holds your application.

Answer (score 1):

## Use Guava's [`RateLimiter`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html).

If you already have Guava in your library path, or if you're interested in adding it, you can use this solution:

```
RateLimiter rateLimiter = RateLimiter.create(10/60d); // 10 permits per 60 seconds.
for (Client c : clients){
  setUpEmail(c);
  rateLimiter.acquire(1);
  sendMail(c);
}
```

Your kind of problem is exactly why `RateLimiter` was created.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter and wait for a minute when ten mails were sent:

```
int counter = 0; 
for (Client c : clients){
  counter++;      
  setUpEmail(c);
  sendMail(c);
  if(counter%10==0){
    Thread.sleep(60*1000); // wait a minute
  }
}
```

This is not ideal since you may lost some time, e.g. when sending ten mails needs 20 seconds, you only may wait 40 seconds before starting a new bulk.

Another option would be to wait between each mail so that the time for 10 mails is at least 60 seconds:

```
for (Client c : clients){     
  setUpEmail(c);
  sendMail(c);
  Thread.sleep(6*1000); // wait 6 seconds
}
```

And a more sophisticated one:

```
int counter = 0; 
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
for (Client c : clients){
  counter++;      
  setUpEmail(c);
  sendMail(c);
  if(counter%10==0){
    long needed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;  // ms needed for ten mails
    Thread.sleep(60*1000 - needed); // wait rest of the minute
    start = System.currentTimeMillis(); // start of the next bulk
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Deque clientsDeque = new ArrayDeque(clients);
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
Runnable task = () => {
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++){
     Client c = clientsDeque.poll();
     setUpEmail(c);
     sendMail(c);
   }
}
executor.schedule(task, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: it would be nice if you added some additional explanation with it